# How to render Page attributes in a model when displayed in StreamField?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have the following `StructBlock` and `Page` model:

```
class PostGrid(blocks.StructBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock()
    post_1 = blocks.PageChooserBlock()
    post_2 = blocks.PageChooserBlock()

    class Meta:
        template = 'post-grid.html'

class BlogIndex(Page):
    body = StreamField([('POSTS', PostGrid()),])

    class Meta:
        template = 'base.html'

class PostPage(Page):
    hero_title =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to render the attributes of `post_1` and `post_2` in the `body` StreamField:

`base.html`:

```
{% for block in page.body %}
    {% include_block block %}
{% endfor %}
```

`post-grid.html`:

```
{{ value.post_1.url }}
{{ value.post_1.hero_title }}
```

`value.post_1.url` renders the URL fine. However, `value.post_1.hero_title` is blank.

How do I render the Page attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `PageChooserBlock()` with no further options specified, Wagtail does not know in advance what the page type will be when retrieving it, and so it returns a basic `Page` instance which only consists of the basic fields common to all page types, such as `title`.

In this case, presumably only pages of PostPage should be allowed for these choosers, so you can specify that in the PageChooserBlock definition:

```
class PostGrid(blocks.StructBlock):
    title = blocks.CharBlock()
    post_1 = blocks.PageChooserBlock(page_type='myapp.PostPage')
    post_2 = blocks.PageChooserBlock(page_type='myapp.PostPage')
    # replace 'myapp' with your app name
```

With this change, the chooser will only allow selecting pages of type PostPage, and on the template, `value.post_1` and `value.post_2` will be returned as full PostPage instances, allowing you to use `hero_title`.

Alternatively, if you aren't able to make this change because there are multiple allowed page types, you can force it to fetch the full page object with `.specific`:

```
{% with value.post_1.specific as post_1 %}
    {{ post_1.url }}
    {{ post_1.hero_title }}
{% endwith %}
```

However, each call to `specific` will make an additional database query.